# Product URL with additional parameters (CE 1.8 & EE 1.13)

Tags: url, ee-1.13, url-rewrite, ce-1.8.0.0

In short: Retrieving a product URL with additional params doesn't work in CE 1.8 & EE 1.13.

URLs have changed with the latest version of Magento. Previously in CE 1.7 and EE 1.12 calling `$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)` from a product list would run through the following stages:

1. `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getAddToCartUrl()`

   - Here it would add the query param "options" with the value "cart"
2. `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getProductUrl()`

   - This method essentially gets a value from the URL model
3. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url::getUrl()`

   - A lot of processing occurs until the URL is finally generated, complete with the query parameters originally passed in

Now, with CE 1.8 and EE 1.13, step 3 `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url::getUrl()` starts like this:

```
$url = $product->getData('url');
if (!empty($url)) {
    return $url;
}
```

Because the products in the list have URL data already, the query parameters are not added and the final URL does not contain `?options=cart`.

**My question: Is this a bug or a feature?**

Comment: Just a side note, we have to add a form_key tag to our add to cart url after a couple of EE1.13 upgrades

Comment: Thanks for the input - by the looks of it Magento will do this automatically in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getAddToCartUrl()` via the core/session singleton. Can you give me an example of the code you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, quite the delta for that class from 1.7.0.2 -> 1.8.0.0! Whereas there are substantial changes this class, and that this is "breaking behavior", it should be considered a bug and should be submitted to EE support.

There is nothing exceptionally novel or edgy about this previously-valid functionality, and even in a minor version update breaking changes should not exist (hence Magento 2).

Comment: Thanks Ben, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.